# Url to stop following a document

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, spfx, spfx-webparts, typescript

I'm working with `TypeScript` and `SharePoint Framework` in **SharePoint Online**.

I know that I can see all documents I follow by typing the following url in my browser:

```
https://[my-tenant]/_api/social.following/my/followed(types=2)
```

My question is :  Is it possible to stop following a particular document using the same approach?

I tried this in my browser:

```
https://[my-tenant]/_api/social.following/stopfollowing(ActorType=1,ContentUri=@v,Id=null)?
@v='[my-tenant]:443/Shared%20Documents/test.docx'
```

But this gives me **HTTP 400 (Bad request)**.

What I really would like to do is to create a function to stop following a document like this:

```
protected StopFollowingDocument(contentUri: string) {
    let rootUrl: string = this.context.pageContext.site.absoluteUrl;
    let restcall: string = rootUrl + "/_api/social.following/stopfollowing(ActorType=1,ContentUri=@v,Id=null)?@v='" + contentUri + "'";
    this.context.spHttpClient.get(restcall, SPHttpClient.configurations.v1);
}
```

But nothing happens when I try the above function.There is no error message and the document is still remains followed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to unfollow a document, you need to make a `POST` request. Currently in your code, you are making a `GET` request.

Modify your code as below in the webpart:

```
protected StopFollowingDocument(contentUri: string) {
    let rootUrl: string = this.context.pageContext.site.absoluteUrl;    
    let restcall: string = rootUrl + "/_api/social.following/stopfollowing(ActorType=1,ContentUri=@v,Id=null)?@v='" + contentUri + "'";
    this.context.spHttpClient.post(restcall, SPHttpClient.configurations.v1, null).then((response: SPHttpClientResponse) => {
      console.log("success unfollowing a document");          
    });
  }
```

Reference - [Following people and content - REST API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/following-people-and-content-rest-api-reference-for-sharepoint)